# Excluding NA in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm new to R and I tried to exclude all the data for which the participants answered less than 17 questions. I tried using the two variations down below.

```
data1  <- data[data$frequency.participant >= 17, ] 

data1 <-data[!(data$frequency.participant <17),]
```

My problem is that both do work, as in, they set the rows for which there are less than 17 answers to NA. But more than showing NA, I want those rows to be deleted. What am I doing wrong?

[Here is an example of what my dataset looked like before running the code. There's some NAs but also answers below 17.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/07Zaj.png)

[Here is an example of after running the code. Now everything below 17 has been replaced with NA.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4DE9O.png)

Comment: That's what those commands should do, are you sure about this? Can you post some sample data using `dput()` on your data and pasting the output in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Not knowing what your data looks like this answer is tentative:
Let's say you have this kind of data:

```
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(
  frequency.participant = c(NA, 11, 22, 33, 44),
  other = rnorm(5)
)

df
  frequency.participant      other
1                    NA -0.8204684
2                    11  0.4874291
3                    22  0.7383247
4                    33  0.5757814
5                    44 -0.3053884
```

If you want to exclude all *rows* in the dataframe where the `frequency.participant` values are < 17 OR where you have `NA` tokens in that same column, you can do this:

```
df[!df$frequency.participant < 17 & !is.na(df$frequency.participant), ] 
  frequency.participant      other
3                    22  0.7383247
4                    33  0.5757814
5                    44 -0.3053884
```

Comment: I get "incorrect number of subscripts on matrix" as outcome when using your code.

Comment: Thank you! Your second code is exactly what I want but I have the same problem... It still shows the NA rows.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is you have NA values in your frequency.participant column, which cannot be evaluated with for ex. NA <= 17. Replace NA's in this column with 0 then use your code.

```
data$frequency.participant[is.na(data$frequency.participant)]=0
```

or alternatively

```
data1  <- data[data$frequency.participant >= 17 & !is.na(data$frequency.participant), ]
```

Comment: I tried your code and now I'm wondering about my number of observations. When I ran my original codes my data set went from 2555 to 2450 observations. When I run your code it's 2555 to 1960. It seems weird that the numbers would change so much.

Comment: @Franzine Because you didn't remove the NA rows before! Try this `sum(is.na(data$frequency.participant))` to see how many missing data you have in your column.

Answer (score 0):

For me is easier to just use `na.omit()`:

```
data1  <- na.omit(data[data$frequency.participant >= 17, ])
```